# CRS with Latitude and Longitude the same way round as Google

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude

I have a set of data with Lat/Lon co-ordinates taken from Google Earth, I've converted the co-ordinates into WKT using a short formula in a spreadsheet, converted to a csv and imported. Unfortunately Google presents its points as Lat/Lon whereas all the CRSs I usually use only seem to understand Lon/Lat. I thought there were conventions for this sort of thing so that GIS systems could talk to one another!

Anyway, does anyone know of a CRS that recognises Lat/Lon, in that order?

- Thought it might be useful to give an example - co-ordinates come to me looking like this "50.698162325700466,-4.674852266907692, 50.69849212863936,-4.674183055758476" my formula converts them to this "MULTIPOINT ((50.698162325700466 -4.674852266907692) (50.69849212863936 -4.674183055758476)). The points are all in England, so you can see they are in Lat/Lon.
- I've just thought that +axis=neu should work as a custom CRS, but it doen't seem to be translating correctly. It's turning the points around as required, but also shifting them about.

Comment: Why not do the reordering in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Tried that, but with a multipoint, there's no way of getting a formula to 'see' which part is the easting and which the northing and swap them round. If it were only one point I could take the first 10 digits and the first ten after the comma and swap them, but not with a multipoint.

Comment: Ordering is somewhat arbitrary, but the stardard is {X,Y}. Well-Known Text is documented as ***requiring*** X,Y order. No *translation* is required, just correct ordering.

Comment: I understand the way WKT 'should' be ordered, but I'm having to deal with several dozen multipoints in the format "N,E N,E N,E". I can't manually turn them all round so was asking if there were any way to get QGIS to recognise that the WKT is in the format y,x not x,y

Comment: "Well-Known" is just that.  There's no reason for *any* software to handle reversed order.  You certainly can reverse the order in your function; in fact, you must.

Comment: I appreciate your support for the WKT format, but this is a question/answer forum. As I have said, manually translating what would amount to nearly 100 co-ordinates for each project is not an option. If you do have a solution (i.e a formula that could do as you suggest), I'd be very grateful to hear it, but simply saying that I 'can' reverse the order without specifying how is not very helpful.

Comment: If you show the formula that you are using, perhaps someone can suggest a modification. (BTW: these aren't answers - they are clarifications on the question).

Answer (score 2):

+axis=neu does in fact work, I had an error in the datum I was using. To clarify; if bringing in WKT that is in the format y,x for whatever reason, using a custom CRS with the axes swapped seems to work.